# ExtJS 4.2.1 can't change Model of Overridden Store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have extended the definition of Store:

```
Ext.define('IMStore', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
  proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : '.im.read',
    reader : {
        root : 'item'
    }
  }
});
```

and I call this like:

```
var gridStore = Ext.create('IMStore',{
    model : type 
});
```

and this works OK the *first* time I call it.   If i subsequently call `Ext.create('IMStore',{model : type })` again with a different `type` value, it seems like the new Store instance has the same Model as the first one I created, even though I passed in a different value.

It seems like maybe the Proxy has to be re-created if the Model is changed?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your proxy configuration is declared directly as the `IMStore` class member, it gets overwritten by the proxy *instance* upon its creation within the first `IMStore` instance. This is why the first-created proxy instance is then shared between all `IMStore` instances. The  first model is shared too because it is linked to the proxy.

To avoid that, move proxy definition inside constructor:

```
Ext.define('IMStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    constructor: function() {
        this.proxy = {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '.im.read',
            reader: {
                root: 'item'
            }
        };
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this limitation does not apply in 5.x & up.